# IM program to support yahoo video calls

Tags: software-rec, protocols, messaging

I have been trying to migrate to Linux from Windows during the past one year. Until I completely deleted my windows and I have been using Linux mint 15 for the last 30 days. I am really satisfied.

I have one huge problem. I have relatives in other countries that I must use Yahoo to chat and talk with. I have tried to find a replacement for Yahoo messenger in Linux that supports Yahoo video/voice calls protocol but I have not been successful. Since I must use Yahoo for my calls I would highly appreciate if you could suggest me a program that I could use.

I have tried different distributions and Linux mint 15 seems to be the most stable on my laptop. So I would like to use a program that is supported by Linux mint.

- I have [tried](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=57323&start=0#p342725) GYchE but unfortunately it does not support video/voice calls
- I have tried installing Yahoo messenger through Wine. I have installed Yahoo Messenger but when it tries to log me in I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtKBP.png) error. It seems to be a common problem for different programs in Wine. But I could not find a solution to solve the problem.

Edit:
I installed VirtualBox and used a Windows XP iso file to install Windows Xp on the virtual Machine. Everything was very easy and straightforward. As Anthon suggested, if you want to use the USB device you should be a member of *vboxuser* group. VirtualBox has a very good Manual here. I followed the manual [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#idp18807712), but in linux mint there is no GUI user/group management tool. So I followed [this](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=88554#p510876) answer to install the tool.
I am so happy that everything (webcam - microphone) is working under the virtual machine Yahoo Messenger. So far it has been really fast and stable.

Answer (score 2):

When I was not able to find anything supporting the protocol I ran the Windows application inside a Virtual Machine (VMware at that time, but it should work on Mint in VirtualBox as well, just make sure you are allowed to use the USB devices).

However since then I have moved to using Skype and Google Hangouts and have not had the need for using Yahoo.

Comment: Oh, I see. I really have no other choice. I must use Yahoo. I would vote up your answer when I get enough reputation. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can use "kopete" for yahoo video calls. You might have to also install libjasper1.
Both of them can be found in ubuntu software center.